# foldl/foldr don't hit stackoverflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

Im reading this https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27, but when I try to replicate code such as

```
foldl k = go
    where
        go z [] = z
        go z (x:xs) = let z' = k z x
            in foldl k z' xs

sum2 = foldl (+) 0
try2 = sum2 [1..10000000]
```

My laptop hangs for a while and evaluates it rather than return a stackoverflow as expected.

Even when I try foldr (+) 0 [1..1000000], I fail to get a stackoverflow unless I increase the size of the list.

Has something changed since the article was written? Any ideas?

I'm loading the file with :l folds.hs, running with stack ghci. I tried the following to reduce my stack size but maybe it was an incorrect way.

`stack ghci +RTS -K2M -RTS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack limit has been increased to [80% of physical memory](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html#rts-flag--K%20%E2%9F%A8size%E2%9F%A9) by default. For setting the option with `stack`, use `stack ghci --ghci-options="+RTS -K2M"`. I did get the overflow this way on GHC 8.8.4.